# Android: Nougat turns off data connection on screen off which does not allow background service to send loaction update on server

Tags: android, service, geolocation

I am developing an android app which has a functionality to send location updates on server using data connection. No wifi only data connection.

**What's happening now:**

1. A service runs in background
2. Service runs location updates using FusedLocationApi
3. On receiving location update, service sends this location on server

Works well in lollipop because lollipop does not turn off data connection on screen off.

For devices above lollipop, data connection automatically turns off when screen turns off due to which location updates are not being sent to server which is very annoying for me. I must have to get rider location updates after 20 to 30 seconds.

Please advice how can I get frequent location updates on server from devices above lollipop. And I am posting this question after searching for solution for 3 days but didn't find any reasonable answer. So please ignore my question.

momersaleem

Comment: Do you use a foreground service already?

Comment: Not yet. Because my minsdkversion is 15.

Comment: @greenapps any suggestions regarding foreground service please?

Comment: What kind of suggestion do you need? You can keep all existing code. Only add some code lines to make it a foreground service.

Comment: @greenapps you mean in case of foreground service, data connection will not lost if user turns off the screen. Am I right?

Comment: `Do you use a foreground service already? `

Comment: you have only one way to achieve that you want: use WakeLocks (it's really bad way cuz of battery consumption)

Comment: I have resolved this problem by using foreground services as mentioned by @greenapps. Foreground services are exempted from doze mode so you can get frequent location updates and network access for this service to update location on server even if your screen is turned off and device is stationary or not.